# Make a page (url) not cacheable

Tags: php, page-template, forms, cache

How to setup a wordpress-page in wordpress as non-cacheable in wordpress?

I have made up a form manually for a page(wordpress) and I want to make that page not cacheable by browsers.

How can it be done?
Right now I am trying "nocache_headers();" function from wordpress, but it is not working.

```
nocache_headers();
```

If I submit data from the form and go back in the browser, it shows up the previous form.

Comment: How your pages are cached ? With a plugin ?

Comment: No, my pages are being cached by default in the browser. I want to make my form pages as non-cacheable so that when I submit a form and go back, it shows the new form.

Comment: So the fields are kept as filled when you go back ? Did you tried `Shift + Reload` once you go back ?

Comment: Yes, the fields are kept filled. Any idea how to change that behaviour. The problem is not in the server but in the browser.

Comment: If you refresh using Shift + Reload, do you still see the values ?

Comment: Nope...I just don't want the fields to be kept same when I go back...Isn't there any wordpress tag or way?

Comment: You can use jQuery to flush the form fields - `$("form").trigger('reset');`

Comment: Nice idea, I will try it..thnx

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with caching, but with form auto-completion. It is happening because the browser is set to store form content. To avoid this, you should generate a random code and add it to the name attribute of your input tags. Then send the random generated number trough another hidden input so you can retrieve the data on the other side.